# White non-gird lines on matplotlib plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, grid

I have been working on a project for my math class in which I am creating a Julia set generator. I had finally succeeded in generating it, but when I show the plot and save the image generated there are white lines all over it. They do not line up with x ticks or y ticks. When I view the saved image it had even more white lines. I have been searching to find what these might be, but I have found nothing.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#Set up window with a name and size.
plt.figure("Julia Set Generator by Eric Kapilik", figsize=(7.0,7.0))
#Set Range of axes
plt.xlim([-2,2])
plt.ylim([-2,2])
#Add labels to axes
plt.xlabel("Real Numbers")
plt.ylabel("Imaginary Numbers")
plt.grid(b=False, which = "major", axis = "both")
plt.grid(b=False, which = "minor", axis = "both")

name = input("Save file as... \n")
#Ask for maximum amount of iterations to base colour 
#selection off of with fractions.
max = int(input("What is the maximum amount of iterations you wish to run?     "))

#Generate an array of colour names to be used to plot points. 
#Set seed of array.
colourArray = ["r"]
for colourNum in range (1, max):
    #if the place in array is between 0% and 25% then set the colour to red. 
    #Same method used for other three colours.
    if colourNum >= 0 and colourNum <= (max/4):
        colourArray.append("r") #red
    elif colourNum > (max/4) and colourNum <= (max/2):
        colourArray.append("y") #yellow
    elif colourNum > (max/2) and colourNum <= ((3*max)/4):
        colourArray.append("g") #green
    elif colourNum > ((3*max)/4) and colourNum <= max:
        colourArray.append("c") #cyan
        
#Get constant value of which the julia set is based off of.
#The real number component is plotted on the horizontal axis
#of a complex number grid so we will use x.
xConstant = float(input("Enter real number constant component: "))
#The imaginary nuber compenent of a complex number is plotted on the vertical axis, 
#so we will use y in our real number grid (for simplicity's sake).
yConstant = float(input("Enter imaginary number constant component: "))

#Title the graph based on the constatn complex number entered.
plt.title(str(xConstant) + " + " + str(yConstant) + "i")




#See the starting coordinates to be tested and conditions
xTest = float(-2)
yTest = float(2)
stop = False
i = 0
xPrevious = xTest
yPrevious = yTest
        
#Using an escape time algorith, determine the amout of iterations of the recursion
#are needed for the coordinate to be attarcted to infinity.
#Continue doing this while the y value of the coordinate being tested is less
#than or equal to -2.
while yTest >= -2:
    #We are following the recursive function of
    #f(Z-1) = Z^2 + C
    #Where Z is current coordinate, and C is the constant value.
    #Reminder: Both Z and C are actually complex numbers but in our case we
    #are using them both as real number coordinates on a real number grid.
    xCurrent = ((xPrevious**2) - (yPrevious**2)) + xConstant
    yCurrent = (2 * xPrevious * yPrevious) + yConstant
    
    #Points that surpass a circle of radius 2 with a centre point at the origin
    #are considered to indefinitely escape to infinity.
    #So when the radius of the recursive coordinate based off of the tested coordinate
    #becomes greater or equal to two we know it will be attaracted to infinity.
    radius = xCurrent**2 + yCurrent**2
    
    #"Is the point an escapee?"
    if radius >= 2:
        #Since the point has been defined as one that esacpes to infintity
        #it is considered an escapee, so set that to true.
        escapee = True

    #"Is the point a prisoner?"
    if i == max:
        #The point is considered a prisoner if max iterations is reached and 
        #the point is still within the circle of radius 2.
        #The testeed point will be considered a prisoner based off of the amount
        #of iterations we selected, it is possible that with more iterations
        #that we would find this to be an escapee.
        prisoner = True
    
    #If we have not defined what kind of point this is yet, then go to the next
    #iteration of the recursion. i is the number of iterations completed for
    #the test point.
    if escapee == False and prisoner == False:
        i = i + 1
        #Out with the old, in with the new. Set the current points to the previous
        #points for the next iteration.
        xPrevious = xCurrent
        yPrevious= yCurrent
    
    #If, however, we have defined the point, then colour it based off of
    #the amount of iterations using the array of colours generated at the
    #beginning to select the colour.
    if escapee == True or prisoner == True:
        #This sets the black points that are prisoners, this is the body
        #of the julia set.
        if i == max:
            colourPoint = "k,"
        else:
            #Colour the point and concatenate a ",", which means to plot this point
            #as a pixel.
            colourPoint = colourArray[i] + ","
        #Plot the point! (Most satisfying part)
        plt.plot(xTest, yTest, colourPoint)
        
        #Determine the percentage finished, to give user an idea of how the
        #renderig is going. (Not nessecary, but appreciable)
        percent = int(((yTest-2)/4) * (-100))
        print(str(percent) + "%")

#After setting a colour and plotting the point, jump to the next test coordinate.
        #Once the end of the line is reached, jump down one.
        if xTest >= 2:
            xTest = -2
            yTest = yTest - 0.01
        else:
            xTest= xTest + 0.01
#Reset the starting conditions.
        i = 0        
        escapee = False
        prisoner = False
        xPrevious = xTest
        yPrevious = yTest

#Show the beauty.
print("100%")
print("Wait for matplotlib to finish things up...\nWill take a minute...")
plt.show()
plt.savefig(name)
```

Plot that was generated:
[image: Plot that was generated.]

Saved image, with even more white lines:
[image: Saved image, with even more white lines.]

Comment: I think this is an aliasing problem - you could either make your points bigger, or try constructing a `colourPoint` array for every point on your `x,y` grid, then plotting that with `pcolormesh` or `imshow`.

Comment: Thanks for your response Tom! I followed the idea of making the points bigger by making the space between them smaller. Increasing the test points by 0.005 instead. Generating now... Should see if this will be answer. Thanks!